# Inkscape Clip Shape and Filter

Tags: inkscape, mask, drop-shadow, clipping-mask

The top layer has a drop shadow, but the shadow should not have any effect on the transparent area outside of the circle.

[image: Pre-clip]

I tried using duplicating the circle and using `Path-->Intersection`,  but that didn't clip the shadow.

[image: Post-clip]

Using `Object-->Clip-->Set` and `Object-->Mask-->Set` remove the shadow entirely, though there may be some setting that could allow them to work that I am unaware of.

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately I doubt there's a solution.

Comment: Not even a "cheat" solution using gradients? Or maybe a specialized mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Inkscape, filter effects like a drop shadow can be clipped by adding the filtered object to a group first, then clip the group.

---

**Tutorial**

[image: 1. Copy the green circle]

1. Copy the green circle (It will be used as the clipping mask later on)  (Ctrl + c)

[image: 2. Select both objects]

2. Select both objects using the Select tool

[image: 3. Create a new group]

3. Create a new group (Object > Group, or Ctrl+g)

[image: 4. Paste the image in place]

4. Paste the image in place (Ctrl+Alt+v)

[image: 5. Add the previously created group to the selection]

5. Add the previously created group to the selection

[image: 6. Set the Clip]

6. Set the Clip (Object > Clip > Set, or right mouse menu > Set Clip)

The end result in an object in which the drop shadow has been clipped!

---

Adding the green circle to the group is actually optional: a group with only the white shape could also be clipped. However that could result in small render artifacts at the bottom of the object.